# JSLint warns about ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, jslint

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
var a = num ? 5 : "five";
```

Code seems to be workable. But JSLint warns like this:

> ```
> #2 Expected '?' at column 9, not column 15.
> var a = h ? 5 : "qwerty"; // Line 10, Pos 15  
> #3 Expected ':' at column 9, not column 19.
> var a = h ? 5 : "qwerty"; // Line 10, Pos 19
> ```

So what the problem is? How to disable such warnings?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Found this online: `"With JSLint you'll get an "Expected '{a}' at column {b}, not column {c}" error any time an incorrect indentation width is found."`

Comment: Seems like you should put more code in here, currently, your `?` is at column `11`.

Comment: When I place it to begin of the line:
 #2 Undeclared 'h'.
    var a = h ? 5 : "qwerty"; // Line 4, Pos 9
 #3 Expected '?' at column 5, not column 11.
    var a = h ? 5 : "qwerty"; // Line 4, Pos 11
Indentation is 1:1 like in question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its *opinion* is that:

> The ternary operator can be visually confusing, so `?` question mark and
>   `:` colon always begin a line and increase the indentation by 4 spaces.
>
> ```
> var a = h
>     ? 5
>     : "qwerty";
> ```

To fix either comply with the rule or tick *messy whitespace*.

Comment: Can you add an example?  Will delete my answer if so... no point having both.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Went ahead and added your example to this answer... Guess you could've too, hope that's not too invasive. It does help explain what the JSLint instructions require.

Comment: @ruffin Fine by me, though personally I don't like to do those sorts of edits when the post isn't CW :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Re: Earlier, now deleted, comment -- The worst part here is that the one person's opinion changes wrt *the same purely subjective decision*. I really like JSLint, and Crockford's yet to be *wrong*, but changing to multiple `var`s on multiple lines, one per variable declaration, and then this one (which is also reasonably new), is driving me a little batty. :( <<< Feelings hurt, as Crockford warned.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yeah, I normally wouldn't either, but you're both within a few minutes of each other, and I hate seeing dueling correct answers where both are missing a [nearly trivial, but useful] part of the other. Today, I'm [your Harvey Keitel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaner_(crime)), I guess.

Comment: The message is misleading. It suggests that the indentation level is wrong, but what's actually missing is linebreaks. "Gee thanks" Doug.

Comment: This still doesn't pass jslint rules, even with whitespace excluded, as it expects something in parenthesis.  I have not found a form of the above that will comply.  This can make JSLint useless if you have more than 10 or so cases as it does not finish analysing the script.